# ViewController is appearing transparent and showing another screen in background

Tags: ios, xcode11

Created this app long before the update for Xcode 11.  While testing my app, I happen to notice that when I seque to another screen, I can see the screen but I can also see another screen in the background.

[image: pic]

you will notice these things in the background are from another view controller, are appearing:
- the title (should only be the image of a user)
- the background pic (this background should be white)
- the "what are you?" message
- rider and driver buttons

Any idea why?

Comment: Sure, it’s because your view has some transparency and your presentation is no longer fullscreen.

Comment: So how can i resolve this?

Comment: You could make your modal segue fullscreen.

Comment: Tried them all ... nothing worked

Comment: Well, I’m just guessing. You have given no info at all about what you’re doing.

Comment: What info do you need?  I am not sure why this is happening

Comment: Well, explain exactly what "when I seque to another screen" means.

Comment: Sorry When i click on a button that takes me to the image of the controller, the screen looks like this

Comment: You should provide more info about how you are presenting your view controller, if you are presenting it on the code, please edit your question to include it. If it's done in interface builder, please attach screenshots of segue properties, and the properties of view controller that's being presented. What @matt meant by making your modal segue fullscreen is that, view controller has a property `modalPresentationStyle`, you can set that to the `.fullScreen` to make it full screen, it can be set on interface builder as well.

Comment: @FahriAzimov Will that take the transparency away?

Comment: Well, I guess it will.

Comment: Do i put it into info.plist? or where? I tried to set the property in the storyboard but that didn't help.

Comment: @FahriAzimov I tried the following in the viewDidLoad in the rSignUpTVC view controller but it crashes with : Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x16d2a7d48)::               
        let signupVC = rSignUpTVC()
        signupVC.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
        present(signupVC, animated: true)

Comment: Ok i fixed it!  On my Navigation Controller, i set the property Presentation to Full Screen and it works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I set the Presentation property of the Navigation Controller attached to the View Controller in question to .fullscreen.